# What is the difference of 2 Rscript.exe executables?

Tags: r

The **R** in my computer is in the path with structure like so...

##### Path

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-x.y.z\bin
```

##### Structure

- `bin`

  - `x64`

    - `R.exe`
    - `Rscript.exe`
    - *other files*
  - `R.exe`
  - `Rscript.exe`

As you can see, there are 2 files named **`R.exe`**. Same thing is true with **`Rscript.exe`**. What are the differences between these redundant files?

Comment: @r2evans I know the difference between *R.exe* and *Rscript.exe*. What I am asking is the difference between the ones inside the `bin` directory compared to the ones inside the `x64` directory.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that, sorry ... R used to ship with both 32-bit and 64-bit variants, though the dual-architecture thing was dropped in R-4.2.0 ... perhaps it's a holdover for compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that they are holdovers from the days when R on windows shipped with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions. In R-4.2.0, they dropped 32-bit<sup>[1]</sup> and now ship only the 64-bit version of R, but there are likely a bunch of tools that still rely on the presence of *both* `c:/R/R-x.y.z/bin/R.exe` and `c:/R/R-x.y.z/bin/x64/R.exe`.

On a quick test I did (R-4.2.3 on windows), they are clearly different files, but the help *suggests* the intent:

```
C:\R\R-4.2.3> R.exe --help
Usage: R.exe [command args]

where 'command args' can be

  --arch n    for n=i386, x64, 32 or 64
  any other arguments listed by R.exe --arch x64 --help

C:\R\R-4.2.3> x64\R.exe --help
Usage: Rterm [options] [EnvVars]

Start R, a system for statistical computation and graphics, with the
specified options

EnvVars: Environment variables can be set by NAME=value strings

Options:
  -h, --help     ...
  --version
  --encoding=enc
  --encoding enc
  --save
  --no-save
  ...
```

(Heavily abbreviated output on the second call, my apologies.)

From the `--help` alone, it looks like the top-level `bin\R.exe` is really a convenience wrapper.

```
C:\R\R-4.2.3> R.exe --arch 32
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

So my informed but not authoritative guess/assumption is that they are both there for a measure of backward compatibility in their convenience wrappers. I might be wrong.

Links:

1. https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html, though it may shift to `NEWS4.html` if/when R-5.0.0 is released (no expected timeline).

Comment: The reason I asked is that I am building a software that executes an R text file in the background via the **`Rscript.exe`**. Does that mean it is better to still call the one from the `bin` directory rather than the `x64` directory?

Comment: Honestly, I think it makes no difference. If I had to wage a bet on one or the other surviving the next major version, I'd lean towards relying on `c:\R\R-x.y.z\bin\Rscript.exe`. (But not by a lot :-)